# How to make Eclipse not mark MathML code in XHTML5 documents as erroneous?

Tags: html, eclipse, google-chrome, firefox, mathml

In the past, I have often written HTML code using `Eclipse` with the `Web Developer Tools`. I was quite happy with it because it interprets the doctype declaration and marks error depending on it.

For example, it marks constructs as erroneous which are disallowed in `XHTML5`, but are allowed in `HTML5` (e.g. missing end tags) if the document is `XHTML5`, but doesn't mark them if the document is `HTML5`.

Now I would like to write an `XHTML5` document which includes `MathML`. I did quite extensive research and found out that the correct way to do so is using the doctype declaration and using namespace attributes as shown in the example below (please note that I am aware that the doctype declaration is optional here, but it doesn't hurt and is not relevant to my problem).

However, I have two problems:

- When serving the document to Firefox (current version) as `application/xhtml+xml`, Firefox shows the expected result, i.e. the text `Square root of two:` followed by the digit `2` *enclosed by the mathematical symbol for the square root*. Neither Chrome (current version) nor IE 11 (patched with all currently available patches) show the square root symbol, though. They just show the text `Square root of two: 2`.
- Eclipse marks three consecutive lines of the source file as erroneous: In the line with the opening `<math>` tag, it says `Undefined attribute name (xmlns).` In the line with the opening `<msqrt>` tag, it says `Unknown tag (msqrt).`. In the line with the `<mn>` element, it says `Unknown tag (mn).`.

How can I change the document to make it work as expected in the major browsers (I am only interested in the current versions - no need for FF 2 or IE 9), and how can I make Eclipse to not show those errors?

I really have done long research, and I also have done some experiments (leaving out the doctype and so on), but to no avail. Could somebody please help me out there?

As a final note, I really need XHTML5 and not "normal" HTML5 documents. I would not like this question to cause a discussion about which is better. I just have to accept certain things as they are.

The document in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>
  Square root of two:
  <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <msqrt>
      <mn>2</mn>
    </msqrt>
  </math>
</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To support different browsers there is probably a JavaScript library, similar to https://www.mathjax.org In Eclipse, do you use the HTML or XML editor?

Comment: Opening this with the XML Editor (rather than the HTML editor) seems to work OK

Comment: @howlger I am using the HTML editor. It underlines the elements / attributes / tags which it isn't happy with with a yellow (dotted?) line and puts a "warning sign" to the left of the respective line (black exclamation mark on yellow triangular background). Do I really need a library to make Chrome show MathML? This is a joke in year 2019, isn't it?

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for the tip. Writing bigger documents with the XML editor is a bit tedious, though ...

Comment: We're open to feature requests, but it's the same tech under both editors.

Comment: @nitind Thanks for kicking in. I don't know too much details about Eclipse, but I can tell so far that it is the only software I am aware of which handles different types of HTML documents correctly at the source code level. Notably, it cares about if it is an XHTML or an HTML document and acts correctly depending on the type. It would be very nice if it could be taught that MathML is OK in (X)HTML5 context, because MathML is *officially included* in (X)HTML5. By the way, I am using Eclipse 2018-12.

Comment: @Binarus Is MathML really officially included in (X)HTML 5? I can't find it at W3C. Do you have a link for that? Browser support see Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML#Web_browsers

Comment: @howlger It is not included in the sense that the MathML specification is incorporated into the HTML5 specification. However, there are some experts who have chosen exactly this wording ("... is part of ...") - unfortunately, I seem to fail to find respective articles right now. But the W3C has this: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/single-page.html#mathml Please note the structure of the document here: `§ 4 "Elements of HTML" -> § 4.7 "Embedded Content" -> § 4.7.17 "MathML"`. IMHO, this at least should mean that MathML is now officially a sort of content which can be embedded into HTML.

Comment: @howlger Some further articles: Already back in 2011, a Microsoft engineer stated in an official Microsoft blog: "... , Presentation MathML is part of HTML5. ..." (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/murrays/2011/07/31/rendering-mathml-in-html5/). The Wikipedia page about MathML states (in the first section of the article): "...  It is part of HTML5 ..." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML). While it might not have been my best idea to repeat those wordings exactly, I think we can agree that every decent browser really should support MathML and that it's a shame that they don't.

Comment: @Binarus It is a shame that everyone complains instead of being constructive. Try to convince the development teams which benefit MathML support will bring. I would like to see more comprehensive SVG and CSS 3 than MathML support. Why don't you use the JavaScript library for cross-browser MathML support?

Comment: @howlger Yes, I'll do that, thanks to the comments here. I'll try to use MathJax. But I had a hard time (playing around for nearly a day) trying to find out what I had done wrong. I *never* would have come to the idea that MathML is supported by exactly *one* browser, so I didn't research in that direction.

Comment: @howlger Regarding contributions: About 18 months ago, I have found a serious bug in Chromium. After reporting it, I was asked to provide an example and to explain the desired behavior. Of course, I already *had* given an example, detailed instructions and the desired behavior when first reporting. Two other guys confirmed the bug. A year later, I got an email asking me to triage the bug; otherwise, it would be marked as solved. It is the latter what happened, because I could not find out how to triage the bug. This is ridiculous, and I surely won't waste my time again with browser folks.

Comment: @Binarus Anyone who likes standards should avoid using IE for good reasons. Support what you love instead of bashing what you hate and be aware that the authors of the software you are talking about are reading here.

Comment: @howlger You are right regarding IE; I did not *really* expect that it would support MathML. I just don't care about Microsoft browsers any more. But I have been quite surprised that Chrome lacks the support for MathML as well. Regarding my criticism, I have no problem with the Chromium folks reading here. I can prove my statements at any time. Although that bug was serious, my efforts with preparing examples and detailed explanations have been ignored, there was no real reaction for a year, and then they have made a fool of me by telling me to triage, but not providing any means to do this.